# React lifecycle loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a react form component - it's got a method that `_handleInputChange` on the updated form input and adds the change to state. I'm trying to add a `_calculatePrice`, which as the name suggests, calculates the booking price. I'm trying to get it to display to the user so that when the input field alters, the price change is reflected.

I'm struggling to figure out how to execute this correctly - I imagine it's a lack of knowledge of react lifecycles, I have read the docs and search for a few questions on stack, however, the answer seems to be evading me. The example included gets stuck in a loop as the `_calculatePrice` method updates a state value which then calls itself again.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**Form.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';

class AddBooking extends Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pitch: this.props.pitch,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
      email: null,
      arrivalDate: this.props.dayQuery,
      departureDate: this.props.dayQuery,
      noDays: 1,
      pitchType: "Standard",
      adults: 0,
      children: 0,
      infants: 0,
      hookUp: 0,
      dogs: 0,
      extraInfo: null,
      price: 0,
      deposit: 0,
      paid: 0,
      subTotal: 0,
      total: 0,
    }

    this._handleDisplay = this._handleDisplay.bind(this);
    this._getRefs = this._getRefs.bind(this);
    this._handleInputChange = this._handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this._calculatePrice = this._calculatePrice.bind(this);
  }


  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._calculatePrice(this.state);
  }

  _getRefs(e) {
    var tempBooking = {
      pitch: parseInt(this.state.pitch),
      firstName: this.state.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.lastName,
      email: this.state.email,
      arrivalDate: this.state.arrivalDate,
      departureDate: this.state.departureDate,
      pitchType: this.state.pitchType,
      adults: parseInt(this.state.adults),
      children: this.state.children,
      infants: this.state.infants,
      hookUp: this.state.hookUp,
      dogs: this.state.dogs,
      extraInfo: this.state.extraInfo,
      price: this.state.price,
      deposit: this.state.deposit,
      paid: this.state.paid
    }

    this.props.addBooking(tempBooking);
    e.preventDefault();
    this._handleDisplay();
  }

  _calculatePrice(data) {
   var price = this.props.bookingPrice.in_season;
   var a = (data.adults * price.adults);
   var c = (data.children * price.children);
   var i = (data.infants * price.infants);
   var h = (data.hookUp * price.hookUp);
   var d = (data.dogs * price.dogs);
   var days = data.noDays;
   var subTotal = a + c + i + h + d;
   var total = subTotal * days;

    this.setState({
      subTotal: subTotal,
      total: total
    });
  }

  _handleDisplay() {
    this.props.addDisplay();
  }

  _handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    var partialState = {};
    partialState[name] = value;
    this.setState(partialState);
  }

  render(){

    var price = this.props.bookingPrice.in_season;

    return (
      <Modal isOpen={this.props.formVisibility} toggle={this._handleDisplay}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={this._handleDisplay}>Add Booking</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <div className="modal-body">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-7">
                <form id="add-booking-form">
                  <i className="fa fa-address-card float-left mr-2 mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h5>Personal</h5>

                  <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                    <div className="form-label-group col-6">
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="firstName" className="form-control" ref="firstName" name="firstName" type="text"  placeholder="First Name"/>
                      <label htmlFor="firstName" className="mx-3">First Name</label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-label-group col-6">
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="lastName" className="form-control" ref="lastName" name="lastName" type="text"  placeholder="Last Name"/>
                      <label htmlFor="lastName" className="mx-3">Last Name</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-label-group">
                    <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="email" className="form-control" ref="email" name="email" type="email"  placeholder="Email Address"/>
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
                  </div>

                  <hr className="mb-4 mt-4"></hr>

                  <i className="fa fa-calendar  float-left mr-2 mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h5>Pitch</h5>

                  <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                    <div className="form-label-group col-6">
                      <input defaultValue={this.props.pitch} onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="pitch" className="form-control" ref="pitch" name="pitch" type="number"  placeholder="Pitch"/>
                      <label htmlFor="pitch" className="mx-3">Pitch</label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-label-group col-6">
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="pitchType" className="form-control" ref="pitchType" name="pitchType" type="text"  placeholder="Pitch Type"/>
                      <label htmlFor="pitchType" className="mx-3">Pitch Type</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group row">
                    <div className="form-label-group col-6">
                      <input defaultValue={this.props.dayQuery} onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="arrivalDate" className="form-control" ref="arrivalDate" name="arrivalDate" type="date"  placeholder="Arrival"/>
                      <label htmlFor="arrivalDate" className="mx-3">Arrival</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-label-group col-6">
                      <input defaultValue={this.props.dayQuery} onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="departureDate" className="form-control" ref="departureDate" name="departureDate" type="date"  placeholder="Departure"/>
                      <label htmlFor="departureDate" className="mx-3">Departure</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <hr className="mb-4"></hr>

                  <i className="fa fa-users  float-left mr-2 mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <h5>Group Details</h5>

                  <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                    <div className="form-label-group col-4">
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="adults" className="form-control" ref="adults" name="adults" type="number"  placeholder="Adults"/>
                      <label htmlFor="adults" className="mx-3">Adults</label>
                      <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">18+</small>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-label-group col-4">
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="children" className="form-control" ref="children" name="children" type="number"  placeholder="Children"/>
                      <label htmlFor="children" className="mx-3">Children</label>
                      <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">12-17</small>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-label-group col-4">
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="infants" className="form-control" ref="infants" name="infants" type="number"  placeholder="Infants"/>
                      <label htmlFor="infants" className="mx-3">Infants</label>
                      <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">4+</small>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                    <div className="form-label-group col-6">                        
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="hookUp" className="form-control" ref="hookUp" name="hookUp" type="number"  placeholder="Hook Up"/>
                      <label htmlFor="hookUp" className="mx-3">Hook Up</label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-label-group col-6">
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} id="dogs" className="form-control" ref="dogs" name="dogs" type="number"  placeholder="Dogs"/>
                      <label htmlFor="dogs" className="mx-3">Dogs</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group row mt-3">
                    <div className="form-group col-12">
                      <textarea className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" placeholder="Extra Info" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group row">
                    <label  className="col-2 col-form-label">Price</label>
                    <div className="col-10">
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} className="form-control" ref="price" name="price" type="number"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group row">
                    <label  className="col-2 col-form-label">Deposit</label>
                    <div className="col-10">
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} className="form-control" ref="deposit" name="deposit" type="number"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group row">
                    <label  className="col-2 col-form-label">Paid</label>
                    <div className="col-10">
                      <input onChange={this._handleInputChange} className="form-control" ref="paid" name="paid" type="number"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div className="col-5">
                <i className="fa fa-calculator float-left mr-2 mt-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <h4>Booking Price</h4>
                <small id="passwordHelpBlock" className="form-text text-muted">
                  Summer Tariff & Forest Pitch
                </small>
                <ul className="list-group list-group-flush mt-3">
                  <li className={"list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center " + (this.state.adults ? 'show' : 'hidden')}>
                    Adults x{this.state.adults}
                    <span className="pull-right">£{price.adults * this.state.adults}</span>
                  </li>
                  <li className={"list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center " + (this.state.children ? 'show' : 'hidden')}>
                    Children x3
                    <span className="pull-right">£{price.children * this.state.children}</span>
                  </li>
                  <li className={"list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center " + (this.state.infants ? 'show' : 'hidden')}>
                    Infants x2
                    <span className="pull-right">£{price.infants * this.state.infants}</span>
                  </li>
                  <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Subtotal (cost per night)
                    <span className="pull-right">£0</span>
                  </li>
                  <li className="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center font-weight-bold">
                    Total
                    <span className="pull-right">£0</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="danger" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this._handleDisplay}>Close</Button>
          <Button color="success" onClick={this._getRefs}>Save</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}

export default AddBooking;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to include duplicate information in your state.

For example, if your state contained `firstName` and `lastName`, you wouldn't need another state for `fullName`.

Try removing `subTotal` and `total` from your state. Instead, calculate it inside of your `render` method. This way, you avoid causing an infinite loop with your `setState` calls.

I created this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/810mnklyw8) that shows a simple example of this.

Comment: When would be an appropriate time to add the total and subtotal to state? I need to add it to a database at some point? Thanks for the answer by the way - I've already marked it as correct

Comment: Generally, you will never need to add the `total` and `subtotal` to state. For your instance of sending it to a database, you can reuse the functions you have to calculate the `total` and `subtotal`.

I updated the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/810mnklyw8) example to show you how you might achieve this.